# Understanding some sample code?

Tags: c++, types, arduino, accelerometer, i2c

I'm trying to get my head around this sample on arduino for the MPU-9150 sensor. It is connected over the I2C bus and it uses this function to sample from the sensor,

```
int MPU9150_readSensor(int addrL, int addrH){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU9150_I2C_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(addrL);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);

  Wire.requestFrom(MPU9150_I2C_ADDRESS, 1, true);
  byte L = Wire.read();

  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU9150_I2C_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(addrH);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);

  Wire.requestFrom(MPU9150_I2C_ADDRESS, 1, true);
  byte H = Wire.read();

  return (int16_t)((H<<8)+L);
}
```

addrL and addrH are two addresses for instance,

```
#define MPU9150_TEMP_OUT_H         0x41
#define MPU9150_TEMP_OUT_L         0x42
```

What i get back over the serial monitor when the values are printed is always -1, i think this is somthing to do with the `(int16_t)` type who's removal does nothing to the printed value but im not sure? Also im not sure why there are two address for getting a single value, H and L and why they are bit shifted and added together? Is it something to do with the I2C bus?

I have a big lack of knowledge here and am trying to understand this so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: The value -1 = 0xFFFF - probably the result of either getting an error value or reading "unconnected input".

Comment: Thanks, you were right, i was just using the wrong address :/ but i still dont understand the need for two addresses H and L (high and low i assume).

Im trying to understand this code from scratch so im not always relying on someone else's code...

Comment: The data is being read as two 8 bit values. It's been a while since I did anything with I2C, but from memory, it's a bus that only deals with 8-bit values. If you need more than 256 distinct values, you then need to use more than one 8-bit value (two or more register locations) to represent those values. So, in this case, the value returned is a 16-bit value, formed of a "low" and "high" part. You could have a 24-bit value from 3 register locations or a 32-bit value from 4 register locations, etc.

Comment: Thanks, i understand that now. This project might take loner than i thought... :)